# Reference Dynamic Named Range dependent on cell value Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to dynamically reference a name range based on the contents of a cell.

For example, I have the following dynamic named ranges:

```
tCat1_Pass
tCat2_Pass
tCat3_Pass
```

Assuming we have the value 2 in Cell A1, I would like to reference tCat2 like the following

```
"tCat"&A1&"_Pass" which would = "tCat2_Pass"
```

INDIRECT doesn;t work with this, are there any other solutions, apart from writing a UDF or using CHOOSE?

Comment: Why not `INDIRECT()` work? Indirect must work. Try `=INDIRECT("tCat"&A1&"_Pass")`.

Comment: I get a #REF! error

Comment: Name range created in the following manner: Example for tCat1: 
`tCat1!$Z$3:INDEX(tCat1!$Z$3:$Z117,COUNTA(tCat1!$Z$3:$Z117))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by writing a small UDF:

```
Public Function nm_return(cat_nbr As Integer, tbl_nm As String)
    
    nm_return = Range("tCat" & cat_nbr & tbl_nm)
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

See below screenshot to use `INDIRECT()` function.

[image]

Comment: Only problem is i want to dynamically use the range in other formulas ie XLOOKUP(value, "tCat"&A1"_Pass")

Comment: @e_conomics As per my screenshot try `=XLOOKUP(4,INDEX(INDIRECT("tCat" & A2 & "_Pass"),,1),INDEX(INDIRECT("tCat" & A2 & "_Pass"),,2),"")`.

Comment: my defined names are on different sheets so that won't work. I have written a small function to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `EVALUATE` within Name Manager, i.e. define *nm_return* as:

`=EVALUATE("tCat"&$A$1&"_Pass")`